# Как подключить kendo UI?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, ui, kendo

Хочу использовать   [DataTimePicker](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datetimepicker/index), но не понимаю как его подключить в asp.net mvc проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас Visual Studio, то устанавливайте приложение - http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/introduction#download. Затем конвертируете существующее приложение - http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/vs-integration/convert-project-wizard. Потом добовляете ваш контрол. Смотрите доки там должно быть все. Надеюсь это поможет!

Comment: спасибо, буду разбираться